# EOL while scanning string literal error

Tags: python, eol

So I'm trying to work with this piece of code

and I get the error   SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Code:

```
def clean_tweet(self, tweet):
    '''
    Utility function to clean tweet text by removing links, special characters
    using simple regex statements.
    '''
    return ' '.join(re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t])
                                |(\w+:\/\/\S+)", " ", tweet).split())
```

What am I missing?

Secondly, when I run this part of the code below I get the error

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'

Code:

```
 # picking positive tweets from tweets
ptweets = [tweet for tweet in tweets if tweet['sentiment'] == 'positive']
# percentage of positive tweets
print("Positive tweets percentage: {} %".format(100*len(ptweets)/len(tweets)))
# picking negative tweets from tweets
ntweets = [tweet for tweet in tweets if tweet['sentiment'] == 'negative']
# percentage of negative tweets
print("Negative tweets percentage: {} %".format(100*len(ntweets)/len(tweets)))
# percentage of neutral tweets
print("Neutral tweets percentage: {} % \
    ".format(100*len(tweets - ntweets - ptweets)/len(tweets)))
# percentage of neutral tweets
print("Neutral tweets percentage: {} % \
    ".format(100*len(tweets - ntweets - ptweets)/len(tweets)))
```

Is it because I'm trying to subtract a list from a list and if so does numpy help?

Comment: put your regex pattern string all on one line

Comment: done, it works. Simple mistake :)

Comment: another error and code above is edited, TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'

Answer (score 2):

Focusing on:

```
print("Neutral tweets percentage: {} % \
    ".format(100*len(tweets - ntweets - ptweets)/len(tweets)))
```

Apparently `tweets`, `ntweets` and `ptweets` are all lists and therefore have lengths. Then I think you could re-write this as:

```
print("Neutral tweets percentage: {} % \
    ".format(100*(len(tweets) - len(ntweets) - len(ptweets))/len(tweets)))
```